# Performance: Creating duplicate file

Tags: php, performance, patterns-and-practices

I have a Web server (Local) and File server(Remote).

I need to create a duplicate of an xml file in the same location with different file name in the File server. The size of the file is random, but the maximum file size can be 45mb, and I have 200 users a day. I'll be using [`ftp_put`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) in transferring files between server. Which is faster and efficient way between the two below?

> a. Upload file to local -> **Upload the file to remote with new name**
>
> b. Read the contents of the remote file and save it to variable ->
>   Create a new file with the contents from the variable in local ->
>   **Upload the file to remote with new name**

I'm not sure how I can benchmark this,so performance wise which is better a or b,why?

Comment: use a database instead?

Comment: @Ewan do you mean use database to store the contents of the xml file? I'm not going to use the contents of the xml file for any future process. But how is that going to help the performance? Thanks

Comment: So if you are just copying the file its hard to do anything with performance, it is what it is. But if you can take a different approach and build each file at the same time you have more options

Comment: Benchmarking should be easy: start a timer before the operation begins, stop the timer when the operation is done, calculate the time difference and put the result somewhere (for example, in a log file). But in theory, both of your suggested ways transfer the file two times over the network, from remote to local and back, so I would not be astonished if it turns out both ways give you similar results.

Comment: @Ewan building each file at the same time is more convenient, but unfortunately the XML is actually a PDF schema which is an input file from the user and will be later used for producing actual pdf file. We have **tool a and b** (receives the XML from web), **tool a** is the one that reads the XML file to produce PDF, while **tool b** will be needing also the XML for another output but this tool is configured to check specific file name format inside a folder. We can't change tool b since it's basically used by other processes and it will be more costly adjustment.

Comment: @DocBrown, yeah that's good idea. But I'm thinking of a better way to benchmark in an environment where there is a heavy stress for the web server because in the wild there will be like >=200 users that will be operating it at the same time but I'm not sure how I can test this way. I can't also find any good reference to read  regarding which is more resource extensive: _uploading file_ **or** _reading a file_. The web has a legacy code btw.

Comment: *"can't also find any good reference to read regarding which is more resource extensive: uploading file or reading a file"* - this depends fully on your hardware & software & network setup, these are things you definitely have to measure, you cannot solve this in theory by reading some paper.

Comment: ... however, if you can find a way to do the operation directly on the file server, without transferring the file  two times over the network, that would be probably faster. However, there does not seem to be a standard way to use ftp for this, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808799/ftp-copy-a-file-to-another-place-in-same-ftp). If you have other services available to access the file server (for example, running shell commands over ssh), that could be used to create a solution.

Comment: If your users are uploading a complete file I don't see how reading the file from the file server, modifying it with the users file, and uploading with a new name does anyhting for you. Depending on the FTP server software, you might be able to do a copy there without transferring a file back to you and resending it with a new name - check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32625670/6867430

Answer (score 1):

Use php function copy instead. It's about 2 x faster than ftp_put.

```php
copy($localFilePath, 'ftp://login:password@host/remoteFilePath');
```